# Java mock function to change its behavior

Tags: java, unit-testing, mockito, spy

I am working on writing a unit test for piece of class like this:

```
public class AClass{
    private List<String> testStringList;

    public void upperMethod(){

        testStringList = new ArrayList<String>();
        // add some thing to the string here
        List<String> newStringList = lowerMethod(testStringList)
        // .......
    }

    public List<String> lowerMethod(testStringList){
        //modify the test string list, like reverse it
        return modifiedString;
    }
}
```

I want to change `lowerMethod's` behavior, when unit testing `upperMethod`.
For example, append the `testStringList` with a new item, instead of reverse it.

After reading the [mockito doc](https://static.javadoc.io/org.mockito/mockito-core/2.7.7/org/mockito/stubbing/Answer.html) I generate some ideas like this:

```
public class testClass{
    AClass aOriginal;
    AClass aSpy;

    @Before
    public void setUp(){
        aOriginal = new AClass();
        aSpy = spy(aOriginal);

        when(aSpy.lowerMethod(any())).thenAnswer(new Answer() {
            public List<String> answer(InvocationOnMock invocation){
                Object[] objects = invocation.getArguments();

                //Get String list from it somehow, and append a new item, return it
            }
        });
    }

    @Test
    //test method later with new lowerMethod behavior
}
```

I think my major question is how to get this idea work? What is the best way to do this?

I've read multiple documents and questions here, my difference is

1. how to pass a list of string through invocation, that is how to extract the list of string for that Object list?
2. in `Mockito.when`, when I pass called with `any()`, the list append function in answer method always return a `java.lang.NullPointerException`.

Comment: This is generally a bad idea.  You're trying to test `AClass`, so mocking its internal implementation details is antithetical to testing whether it works.

Comment: Yeah, that makes sense. I am trying another way to test the behavior.
But let's just say if the 'lowerMethod' lives in another class, how to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just to make that clear: *You should **not** "spy" or "mock" the class under test.* You "spy" or "mock" its *dependencies* ie.: other classes providing *business logic* your tested class collaborates with.  The need of *spying* your testes class usually points to a *design problem*.

---

You only need the `mock.*Answer()` form if the *return value* of this mocked method depends on the parameter of the mocked method. This is usually not what you want.

Usually you want to return a *very specific configured return value* for the current test case (method). Therefore you should not configure the mocks in the *setup* method in  the first place, especially if this implies the use of `mock.*Anser()`.

Answer (score 4):

When you are working on a spy, you should be using the `do().when()` syntax. This will prevent the test from invoking the actual implementation.

Also try to go for a more specialized `Mockito.any(List.class)` instead of the generic `Mockito.any()`:

```
@Before
public void setUp(){
    aOriginal = new AClass();
    aSpy = spy(aOriginal);

    doAnswer(new Answer() {
        public List<String> answer(InvocationOnMock invocation){
            Object[] objects = invocation.getArguments();

            //Get String list from it somehow, and append a new item, return it
        })
    .when(aSpy).lowerMethod(any(List.class)));
    });
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Another approach would be to extend Aclass and implement lowerMethod with whatever functionality you want:

```
public class testClass {

    AClassForTest aClass;

    @Before
    public void setup() {
        aClass = new AClassForTest();
    }

    private class AClassForTest extends AClass{
        @Override
        public List<String> lowerMethod(List<String> testStringList) {

            //append a new item, do whatever you want
            return someList;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Method of RestClientService.java -** This is core class which basically communicate with external HTTP RESTClient. Hence, This class to be mocked here ( JUnit Test).

```
public <T> T execute(HttpUriRequest httpUriRequest, ResponseHandler<? extends    T> responseHandler) throws IOException {
    return this.getClient().execute(httpUriRequest, responseHandler);
  }
```

So, At the Service level class, above method are being called more than once with different handler in a Service method....
Hence, defining the handler behaviour base on the method calling ...

```
Mockito.when(RestClientService.execute(Mockito.anyObject(), Mockito.any(ResponseHandler.class))).thenAnswer(answer);
```

Define the behaviour using Answer -

```
private Answer<Object> answer = (InvocationOnMock invocationOnMock) -> {
    SearchAccountResponseHandler searchAccountResponseHandler = new SearchAccountResponseHandler();
    if (invocationOnMock.getArgumentAt(1, ABCResponseHandler.class) instanceof ABCResponseHandler) {
        return new ABCResponseHandler().handleEntity("response as expected for this handler");
    }
    if (invocationOnMock.getArgumentAt(1, XYZResponseHandler.class) instanceof XYZResponseHandler) {
        return new XYZResponseHandler().handleEntity("response as expected for this handler");
    }
    return new HttpOkResponse(HttpStatus.SC_OK, "default response");
};
```

Finally, in the end, this solution is for my test scenario.